# Using Python with Twitter API (Getting 215 error)

Tags: python, twitter

I'm new to using APIs and I'm trying to simply use the twitter API to search for tweets. I followed the development guide on twitter, but it's still giving this json code. {u'errors': [{u'message': u'Bad Authentication data', u'code': 215}]}

```
consumer_key = xxx
consumer_secret = yyy
token = base64.b64encode(consumer_key + ":" + consumer_secret)
headers = {'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + token, 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'}
data = {'grant_type' : 'client_credentials'}
url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token'
resp = requests.post(url, data = data, headers=headers)  
d = resp.json()
access_token = 'Bearer ' + d['access_token']

tweets = requests.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=python')
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

The Twitter API does not allow access without authentication, you might have problems with the credentials, check this [article](http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth/) that explains AUTHENTICATING Twitter API.

One more thing, try to use [Tweepy](http://www.tweepy.org/), it's an easy-to-use Python library for accessing the Twitter API.

Here's a quick example on how to use it. It seems that you were fetching all the tweets related to `Python`.

For more [details](http://www.pythoncentral.io/introduction-to-tweepy-twitter-for-python/)

```
import tweepy 
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json


#Use your keys
consumer_key = '...'
consumer_secret = '...' 
access_token = '...'
access_secret = '...'


auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)


class TweetListener(StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
      print "tweet " + str(status.created_at) +"\n"
      print status.text + "\n"
      # You can dump your tweets into Json File, or load it to your database

stream = Stream(auth, TweetListener(), secure=True, )
t = u"#python" # You can use different hashtags 
stream.filter(track=[t])
```